# C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'pswds.DOMAIN.Model.Account'

Tags: c#

So this is my first attempt of creating WPF with local sql database.
I have migrated sucessfully and the databases has been created with no issues.

My issue comes when i try this:

```
        public async Task<Account> AddBrand(string userName, string password, string masterPassword, string dateCreated, string dateUpdated)
    {
        try
        {
            if (userName == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Username cannot be empty!");
            }
            else
            {

                Account br = new Account
                {
                    userName = userName,
                    password = password,
                    masterPassword = masterPassword,
                    dateCreated = dateCreated,
                    dateUpdated = dateUpdated
                };
                return await _crudServices.Create(br);
            }
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This is how i defined my _crudServices:

```
        public AccountCrudServices()
    {
        _crudServices = new GenericDataService<Account>(new AccountContextFactory());
    }
```

I get these two errors:

1. Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to pswds.DOMAIN.Model.Account
2. on this return await _crudServices.Create(br); i get the error "_crudServices is not null here"

I expected this to work, with no problems.

Any help or advice is appreciated

Comment: `_crudServices.Create(Account)` probably doesn't return what you expect. Can you please share the implementation of that method?

Comment: Like here?`private readonly IDataService<Account> _crudServices;`

Comment: No, what does `_crudServices.Create` return? I'd expect that to be `void` i.e. it doesn't return anything, since that's what the error says.

Comment: Also, where are you getting the `IDataService<T>` from?

Comment: "_crudServices is not null here" - this should be a warning (static code analysis) and not an error. Code must compile.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `_crudServices.Create` is a method that returns `void`. Now you return the "result" of this `void` method from a non-void method:

```cs
// Return tye 'Account'
public Account GetAccount()
{
  // Compiler error: expects a Account return type. 
  // But instead found return type void: cannot convert void to Account
  return VoidMehtod();

  // Correct return type. 
  return AccountMehtod();
}

private void VoidMethod() 
{}

private Account AccountMethod() 
{}
```

You obviously meant to return the created `Account` instance:

```cs
public async Task<Account> AddBrand(string userName, string password, string masterPassword, string dateCreated, string dateUpdated)
{
  try
  {
    if (userName == null)
    {
      throw new Exception("Username cannot be empty!");
    }
    else
    {
      Account br = new Account
      {
        userName = userName,
        password = password,
        masterPassword = masterPassword,
        dateCreated = dateCreated,
        dateUpdated = dateUpdated
      };
      
      await _crudServices.Create(br);
   
      // Return the correct type
      return br;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Please note that your exception handling doesn't make sense and is dangerous as it introduces potential silent bugs.
There is no reason to explicitly throw an exception only to catch it in the same method. This is a serious code smell you must avoid.

- Exceptions are not meant to create a control flow. Instead use *if-else* and avoid exceptions by checking arguments *before* passing them to a method.
- Exceptions are making your application very slow.
- Never catch `Exception`. Always catch the expected type you want to handle (e.g. `OperationCanceledException`). If you can't handle an exception let it crash the application. Otherwise you won't be able to find those critical errors later. All you create is a buggy nightmare.
- Do not throw exceptions of the base type `Exception`. Always throw a meaningful subclass of `Exception`. In your case it should be [`ArgumentNullException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception?view=net-8.0#remarks). Altzernatively create custom exceptions by extending `Exception`.
- always *rethrow* exceptions properly. Don't catch the original and throw a new one! Otherwise you erase the original stack trace and lose the origin of the exception. Always maintain the complete call stack. Never do:

```cs
// Wrong
try
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Danger: creates a new call stack!
  // Original call stack gets dumped: no chance to trace the exception 
  // back to the original line that originally threw.
  throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}

// Correct
try
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Handle exception and rethrow 
  // without manipulating the original call stack (and exception message).
  throw;
}

// Correct
try
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Handle exception and rethrow without manipulating the original call stack.
  // Add a custom message and 
  // wrap the original exception instance 'ex' using the appropriate constructor.
  // The wrapped exception will be available as inner exception.
  throw new ArgumentNullException("New exception message, ex);
}
```

To check for NULL-strings and empty strings use [string.IsNullOrWhitSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-8.0).
You improved code would look like as follows:

```cs
public async Task<Account> AddBrand(string username, string password, string masterPassword, string dateCreated, string dateUpdated)
{
  if (username == null)
  {
    // If this is not a library method, avoid throwing this exception. 
    // Instead return an empty result or validate the arguments before you pass them on.
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(username), "Username cannot be empty!");
  }
   
  Account br = new Account
  {
    userName = userName,
    password = password,
    masterPassword = masterPassword,
    dateCreated = dateCreated,
    dateUpdated = dateUpdated
  };
      
  await _crudServices.Create(br);
  return br;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am aware thaty i need to make more checks, this is very early stage, but i  did learn how to properly retrun  such values ha ha. So thank you for tour help :)